# Dynamic creation of objects and population with data

Tags: java, design-patterns

I dynamically create objects. These objects have to be populated with data. My concept of solution to this is to store some example data in the file, load it at run time to the array, and then randomly create object based on the array data that will be passed to the factory, and later to appropriate constructor. I forgot to mention that the record in the file stores info on what type of object this record is going to create.

I wonder if this is too cumbersome? If yes what is the better way to dynamically create object and populate them wit data?

Comment: Your question is very opaque.  Try explaining things more clearly and perhaps add some code samples.

Comment: The key point is what data? Random, regular(generated), or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your statement, you are reading and loading data from files outside of factory but I think a good design strategy will be when your Factory will take the responsibility of reading the input from the file, loading it and create the objects as per records. In this way you can De-couple the logic whether its coming from File or From Database. Moreover, You can define all the relevant method to create the objects inside factory only.

Comment: Is it wise to store in the record in the file information of what type this record is? I mean info of what type the factory should create. Otherwise how the factory will know which type to use? I am not sure I am doing this right.